# commit statement missing for a dml statement in binary log

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

I have noticed 'commit' statement missing for a DML statement in binary log. Does it mean that this statement is rolled back in server? I am using mysql 5.5.40.

### sample binlog

at 159527792

160229 23:25:22 server id 104  end_log_pos 159528127   Query   thread_id=45195 exec_time=0     error_code=0(in comments)

SET TIMESTAMP=1456809922/*!*/;

update table_name set col1=4 where col2=4
/*!*/;

at 159528275

160229 23:25:22 server id 104  end_log_pos 159528484   Query   thread_id=45195 exec_time=0     error_code=0(in comments)

SET TIMESTAMP=1456809922/*!*/;

insert into table_name values (1)
/*!*/;

at 159528632

160229 23:25:22 server id 104  end_log_pos 159528511   Xid = 22993533(in comments)

COMMIT/*!*/;

As per mysql documentation

**Binary logging is done immediately after a statement or transaction completes but before any locks are released or any commit is done. This ensures that the log is logged in commit order.**

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/binary-log.html

please let me know whether my undersatnding is correct or not. if any statement getting rolled back, server write rollback to binlog?

Answer (score 0):

mysql will write rollback to binary logs provided the transaction has mixture of engines (myisam and innodb tables). As the myisam can not be rollbacked.

I guess you'd like [this piece of documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/binary-log.html)...

> ... This ensures that the binary log reflects the exact data of InnoDB
>   tables, and so, that the slave remains in synchrony with the master
>   (not receiving a statement which has been rolled back).